# Equation for Horizontal Asymptote (Angle of Shot Put)

Tags: trigonometry

Simple trig problem I can't grok.

$\theta=arcsin\left(\sqrt \frac{v^2}{2v^2+64h}\right)$  (A model for $\theta$ that achieves the greatest distance for a shot-putter.)

Set h fixed at 6 and regard $\theta$ as a function of v. As v gets larger and larger, the graph approaches a horizontal asymptote. Find the equation of that asymptote. The answer is $\theta=45^\circ$, but I can't work out how to get there. This is a pre-calc trigonometry question so I must be missing something obvious.

I tried setting h=6 and solving for v, but I can't reduce v to a single term. I get stuck at $sin^2\theta(2v^2+384)=v^2$.

Comment: If $v$ is large, then $64h$ is a mosquito dropping in comparison to $2v^2$.  So you might as well see what happens, when $h=0$. To justify the conclusion you can rewrite the square root as
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2+\frac{64h}{v^2}}}.$$ What can you say about the denominator when $v^2$ is much larger than $64h$?

Comment: Yea, that was part a, and easy enough to work out to 45$^\circ$.

Comment: Have you done limits and/or continuity? Then you can let $v\to\infty$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yup, I have, and I understand what you're saying. I guess the problem was really just a pre-calc exercise in thinking about ignoring the 64h term and realizing the answer was the same as part a. Thanks.

Comment: Great! Well done. You can post your reasoning as an answer to get more feedback.